# How to check C-code errors for the entire project by Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, intellisense, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using VSCode for C-code development. When I open a file, it will check that file for errors. But I will not see any other file errors, so I will have to manually open the files one by one.
How can I make VSCode scan the whole project for errors without having to open each file one by one manually?

Comment: If you build a project, all files will be compiled and the compiler will report on each file the errors and warnings i finds.

Comment: Thanks you. That's true. What I want to do is batch the files with errors in the explorer on the left side of the VS Code screen and show the whole error on the problem screen (Ctrl + Shift + M). Just like If I open the files one by one.